# Parse JSON to javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string like this one:

```
{
    "products":{"56":"productName","28":"productName"},
    "excludedProducts":{"83":"productName","1":"poductName"}
}
```

So what I want is to get an object in javascript which looks like this:

```
{
     products: {
         "56": "productName",
         "28": "productName"
     },
     excludedProducts: {
         "83": "productName",
         "1": "productName"
     }
}
```

But JSON.parse() converts numbers into indexes and I get

```
{
     products: {
         28: "productName",
         56: "productName"
     },
     excludedProducts: {
         83: "productName",
         1: "productName"
     }
}
```

So basically, is there a way to preserve order of elements after parsing the string formatted like that?

Comment: No. [JavaScript objects are not ordered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: yes just use alphanumeric syntax for key. like **k_28** so the order will not change.

Comment: Pass the products as arrays instead of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of ***Arrays*** to preserve the formatting.

Comment: Right. My bad. I ended up using JSON formatted like this:
    {"products":[[25,"productName"],...],"excludedProducts":[[83,"productName"],...]}